# How do I get a list of all the available keyboard layouts in X.org?

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout

I know these layouts have two-letter codes like `us` for the US layout. I need a list of all the layouts available and also to pair the two-letter codes to the proper names of the layout to get the not so trivial ones.

Comment: Does the following link help with your question?

[How do I enumerate all available keyboard layouts in X.org?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268572/how-do-i-enumerate-all-available-keyboard-layouts-in-x-org

Comment: That one sounds interesting but I need a step by step guide to use that. My knowledge of Ubuntu peeks at I can install and run it from an USB flash drive. There is no clear documentation on X.org-s home page of the available layouts? That would seem logical from an open source project.

Comment: `localectl list-x11-keymap-layouts` ... see `localectl --help` for other options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a text editor. Copy the code from [the stackoverflow question mentioned in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268572/how-do-i-enumerate-all-available-keyboard-layouts-in-x-org) to the file. Save the file with the name "getkbdlayouts.py".

Then open a console window. In that window, type

```
chmod +x getkbdlayouts.py
./getkbdlayouts.py
```

You may get an error like `ImportError: No module named lxml.etree`. If so, you need to install the package python-lxml (usually by running `apt-get python-lxml`).